# Access: get the result from a request in a field of table

Tags: database, ms-access, request

I have a table with fields, I would like that the last field be the result of a request with the parameters of the others fields, it is possible ? I use Access...

[image]

To make simple,I would like to know if it is possible to have a request in the field value with parameters which are subject, date_value and date_observ from this table to get information in others table ?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the requested output.

Comment: Don't save this calculated value into table, calculate in query when needed. However, not really understanding the calculation wanted. Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the edit is given

Comment: @Gustav some idea for helping me ?

Comment: @June7 some idea for helping me ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking for, neither what data you have - and these even seem identical as you have posted the same picture twice. And how can a date be _A1_? I guess you must rephrase this completely.